# Dropdown lists on https version of Stack Exchange have http links

Tags: bug, ssl, achievements-dialog

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open some of StackExchange sites, for example https://stackoverflow.com
2. Click one of the links in "Recent achievements" dropdown list on the navbar
3. Watch the http://stackoverflow.com address in browser's address bar

The same about "Recent inbox messages" dropdown list.

Comment: @Catija: What to do if I will sometimes encounter a bug that relates only to StackOverflow?

Comment: That's what [meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) is for. :)

Comment: @Catija: Oh, thank you. Didn't know about this site.

Comment: You are right. But that post is two years old and the bug is still here. There is a statement that those lists contain only `//`, but I see the explicit `http://`